# Program nodeMCU Over the Air (OTA)

Tags: serial, uploading, nodemcu

I have a Lolin NodeMCU V3 with a broken USB port: no power, no data.

It does show up on WIFI as `AI-thinker_xxx`, I can connect, but what can I do next?

Is there a way to program the NodeMCU Over the Air (OTA), or through some pins?

[Description found here](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/) under V3

Comment: To clarify, if it shows up with that WiFi Access Point name, it is getting power. So the USB cable is working that much at least?

Comment: Also, if you can include a link to the exact hardware you have or a photo that would assist with figuring out what other pins would be helpful.

Comment: Nope, powered over shield.

Answer (score 1):

If powering over Vin pin is working, you can use the board without USB.

ESP8266 is bootloaded over UART pins. These are pins marked RX or D9 and TX or D10 on the NodeMcu board. You can use USB to TTL serial adapter to bootload (flash) the esp8266. To put the esp in flashing mode hold the FLASH button and click the RST button and then release the FLASH button.

You can then upload a sketch with ArduinoOTA library and do following uploads over OTA. After USB upload of a sketch, reset the board with RST button before doing the first OTA upload.